# Enabling CORS for IGDB using ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, cors

So I've been at this issue for hours now but cannot figure it out. I've been trying to use the IGDB API using the ruby gem [igdb_api](https://github.com/igdb/igdb-api-ruby) but keep getting a 403 Forbidden exception. I'm running the server locally for development at `localhost:3000`. Here is how I setup my test code:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def home
    ...
  end

  def games
    # initialize with api_key
    Igdb.connect(ENV['IGDB_API_KEY'])

    puts Igdb::Game.count
  end
end
```

I've been trying to use [rack-cors](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) to fix this but nothing changes. So I'm not sure if I'm missing something obvious. Any help would be great! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think cors is an issue.

CORS basically prevents web-browser from making requests to services outside of current domain.

403 errors means some authorization problems.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a different gem for accessing the api, one called [igdb_client](https://github.com/darkstego/igdb_client).

While I then had a SSL_connection error since I'm on Windows, it was easily fixed by following this quick solution here: https://superdevresources.com/ssl-error-ruby-gems-windows/.

Hope it'll help anyone in the future!